# Is there a way of finding out which network address is the active one?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have a method that will loop through the network addresses on an android phone using C# in xamarin forms, can anyone tell me how i can see which device is the active device?

The reason why I ask is because on some android phones that I have tested on this will give more than one adaptor!

Here is my code example which will list the devices...

```
    public static void NetworkAdresses()
    {
        int i = 0;
        string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostByName(hostname);
        Adresses.Clear();
        foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
        {
            Adresses.Add(new Adress 
            { 
              id = i,
              address = $"{address}"
            });
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem I was having, "There is probably a much cleaner way of doing this, and I realize if the user has multiple active hardware devices such as bluetooth or data, this may not give the required result" but for now after testing on a few devices it gave me the required result.

Here is my code, if anyone can better this, or give a solution for if the user has Bluetooth and/or data device active as well as wireless, you are welcome to give and example on how I would code this into my methods.

```
// create a host instance of the users phone
public static IPHostEntry ihe = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());

public static string GetCurrentDeviceIp()
{
   int i = 0;
   string IP = "";
   foreach (IPAddress address in ihe.AddressList)
   {
       if (IsReachable($"{address}"))
       {
           IP = $"{address}";
           break;
       }
       i += 1;
   }
return IP; 
}


// Check if the current IP is online
public static bool IsReachable(string host)
{
    try
    {
        bool HasConnectivity = false;
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions
        {
            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            DontFragment = true
        };
        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(host, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) HasConnectivity = true;

    return HasConnectivity;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to determine if the app has access to a server with a given IP address ? If so , you could check the following code .

```
IPAddress IP;
if(IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1",out IP)){
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try{   
        s.Connect(IPs[0], port);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // something went wrong
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, My app needs to determine which address is used on the local network, when I use the code I posted using my android 5s, it will only give one result, so obviously it is easy to determine that this is the wifi and I can browse the shares, how ever, the problem comes on other devices that even when they have all other devices disabled, such as bluetooth and so on, it still shows up more than one in the list. Currently my app is using ...  ```public static IPHostEntry ihe = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
        public static IPAddress MyIp = ihe.AddressList[0];```

Comment: To get the current ip address, I then use this to scan the network for a list of IP's on this range, but this of cause is going to run into problems, which it has done now, because some phones are showing more devices with my posted code, one device even gave me a 10.1.0.0 subnet, which we could not find when looking on that phone.

Comment: I have tried this in a method, the problem is that te s.Connect is a void method and has no return, is there anyway I can do something similar and return a value?

Comment: If the IP is unavailable , it will go into Exceptions  Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connect?view=netcore-3.1.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I will test this in a moment, so if i am not mistaken about what you say :-), I need to check the exceptions for the required info?

Comment: You could check the docs and it provide the different Exceptions  of socket .

Comment: I aim looking now, also, I have written a small method using your implementation```     public static bool IsConnectableAdress(IPAddress IP)
{
    bool IsConnectable = false;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1", out IP))
    {
      Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
      SocketType.Stream,
      ProtocolType.Tcp);
       try
       {
          s.Connect(ihe.AddressList[0], 80);
          IsConnectable = true;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
                    return false;
                }
}```

Comment: Not sure if I should use a port because its only for a local network!

Comment: My code is just a demo and you could improve it as you want

Comment: I just tested, and of cause I realized that this is testing devices on the network, sorry if I was not clear, I need to test the internal devices to see which one is being used to access the network. :)(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213778/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-mark).